# Need help in connecting to a HTTPS url with Ruby and passing source data to Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, https, nokogiri

I'm trying to get a list of stations from this webpage - https://web.barclayscyclehire.tfl.gov.uk/maps

I see that they have the list of stations in JSON structure in the javascript. So I am trying to connect to the page and then pass the data to Nokogiri to get the javascript with JSONs and then parse the JSONs individually.

To connect to HTTPS and pass data to Nokogiri I used this code available here - https://gist.github.com/1037492

```
require 'net/https'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "https://example.com"
url = URI.parse( url )
http = Net::HTTP.new( url.host, url.port )
http.use_ssl = true if url.port == 443
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if url.port == 443
path = url.path
path += "?" + url.query unless url.query.nil?
res, data = http.get( path )

case res
  when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
    # parse link
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
     # do what you want ...
  else
    return "failed" + res.to_s
end
```

However when I try to debug in Aptana Studio 3, before the debugger can stop on any breakpoint I have, it exits giving me an invalid return error. Is there something wrong with that code ?
And is that the best way to connect to HTTPS and pass data to Nokogiri ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
doc = Nokogiri::HTML open(https_url)
```

Comment: It works which is awesome, but I get this warning  - `warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER` and I get this error now when debugging- `Uncaught exception: superclass mismatch for class RemoteInterface`

Comment: The warning you can ignore but I haven't seen that error before, and I'm not sure what you mean by debugging.

Comment: By debugging I mean, trying to debug in an IDE like Aptana

Comment: I don't use Aptana so I can't help with that, you should post another question and tag it with aptana and ruby

Comment: I get the warning in irb. Doesn't seem to affect performance.

Comment: I also get the warning in a script

Comment: I get an error that crashes the script : `SyntaxError: [path] dynamic constant assignment`. Ruby 2.2, in Rails console. Seems to work outside of Rails console ?

Comment: does this code mean that the client will no longer try to verify the certificate from the server, thus it can no longer prevent man in the middle attacks?